# Retrieve all files name from the request in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

This should be easy, but I can't get it to work. I have a file input that can upload multiple files.

```
<input type="file" class="input" name="images[]" multiple>
```

When I use `dd($request->images),` I get an array of the `UploadedFile` class containing all the files in the request. See picture below:

[image: Uploaded class array]

Inside one of them, it looks like this:

[image: Uploaded file info]

I want to get the names only. As you can see in the above picture, there is a property called `originalName` with the file name `gomez.jpg.` How can I get all those names from the request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getClientOriginalName()` function to get name of one file and using loop you can get all names.

```
foreach($request->images as $image){
    $names[] = $image->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

Here, $names variable will have all the names.